# using jquery each to get values from form and send it as an ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

As every developer wants, I wanted to make my code short and simple. but makes sense.

I have this edit profile field that have several fields, about 10 text box and 2 radio buttons.

In a simple login form, i could just get the values of username and password like this:

`$("#username")` and `$("#password")`
and assign them into a variable `username` `password` respectively,

That will become like this: (in ajax)

```
$.ajax({
    url : some_url,
    data: {
        username : username,
        password : password
    success : something
    }
});
```

but what if i have several fields, i don't want my code to be super messy, having all those  assignments.

so i come up with an idea of having a key-value pairs that will be based on their input-id

```
var object;
$("#formUpdate:input").each(function(){
      var key = $(this).attr('id');
      var value = $(this).val();
      object.key = value;
});
```

question, what am i missing out, i can't make it work though, are there better ways to do it. Do you think hard-coding it is much better.

Thanks much guys! It's my birthday today btw.

Comment: You should be able to just use `$(form).serializeArray()` though that's based on the input's name, not it's id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong syntax to add a dynamic key to an object. You need bracket notation `["string"]`

```
var obj = {};
$("#formUpdate :input").each(function(){ 
    var key = $(this).attr('id'); 
    var val = $(this).val(); 
    obj[key] = val; 
});
```

though you should be able to just do:

```
var obj = $("#formUpdate").serialzeArray();
```

assuming your inputs also have name attributes.

Edit: you were also missing a space in your input selector.

Comment: didn't know there is a serializeArray function. But anyway it's always nice to do things like what i did, then ask later. hehehehe. thank you so much kevin!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass them as key: **value : pairs** .. Try this

If you want to store as Array of Objects ..

```
var arr = [];
$("#formUpdate :input").each(function() {
    arr.push( { $(this).attr('id') : $(this).val() }) ;
});​
```